# Hudson cancel do not cancel all processes

Tags: build, makefile, hudson

I'm working with hudson v 1.323 installed as a Windows service on Windows XP.  I'm building with a shell script that looks like this:

```
#!c:/cygwin/bin/sh 
export PATH=/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin:$PATH
make -j 4 $MAKE_TARGET
```

When I cancel this build using the red X everything seems to have stopped on Hudson, but when I look in the Windows processes there is still a lot of "make" and "sh" running.  I'm using make v.3.80 of cygwin.

Any help on how to get all the processes killed by Hudson?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to look at Hudson's thread dump to see if thread with your job is still running. It might also give you an indication of why tread is not interrupted.

Thread dump can be seen right from hudson web console:
http://yourserver/hudson/threadDump